# How to iterate over an Yaml in rust using Serde::yaml?

Tags: rust

I am using `Legion` crate and It has an option to `serde` the world. I am using `serde::yaml` to convert it to Yaml and it has all the entities in one object (`Value`). I want to split this into separate entity so that I can write each entity separately in a file. How can iterate over each item in the yaml?

My yaml from Legion looks like,

```
---
Entities:
  Entity 1:
    Name: E1
  Entity 2:
    Name: E2
  Entity 3:
    Name: E3
```

I wanted 3 yamls like below,

```
Entity 1:
    Name: E1
```

```
Entity 2:
    Name: E2
```

```
Entity 3:
    Name: E3
```

I tried below code but it panics saying entities is not a sequence,

```
    let yaml_serde_sequence = yaml_serde["entities"].as_sequence().unwrap();
    for (i, entities) in yaml_serde_sequence.iter().enumerate() {
        let yaml_as_str = serde_yaml::to_string(entities).unwrap();
        println!("{}", yaml_as_str);
    }
```

Comment: Well I guess entities is a hashmap.

Comment: It's unclear how to answer you, why do you want to do that ? if legion have this option it's probably want to serialize the world as one file and not multiple. Why do you want multiple files ? Also please provide link to the legion crate

Comment: The reason is Legion is designed for gaming and I am using it to process files. Each entity is a processed file and I want to dump them.

Comment: You are right :) Thanks! `as_mapping` worked. Again thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve desired result by using `as_mapping` instead of `as_sequence`

```
let yaml_serde_tuple = yaml_serde["entities"].as_mapping().unwrap();
for (i, entities) in yaml_serde_tuple.iter().enumerate() {
    let yaml_as_str = serde_yaml::to_string(entities.1).unwrap();
    println!("{}", yaml_as_str);
}
```